# How do I set up appendices?

Tags: appendices

I used the following command for setting up an appendix section:

```
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
```

(I don't want to use `\appendix`)

Equations work fine, they have A.1, A.2, etc. Yet, whenever I refer to an appendix in the text using `~\ref{appendix:name_of_appendix}`, I get a consecutive number from the sections (a numeral) instead of a reorder appendix section name (A, B, C, etc.).
Any ideas what's wrong? (I re-ran pdflatex several times.)

I use it as follows:

```
We see in Appendix~\ref{appendix:a} that ...

[...]

\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}


\section*{Appendix A: xxx}
\label{appendix:a}
```

Comment: Is `\section*` a typo?

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if we knew what is wrong with `\appendix` for your needs.

Comment: The \appendix command is redefined using a style package that I use. The redefinition exactly defines a macro that does what I described above. I want to use this package, and I would rather not change it.

Comment: \section* is not a typo, it means that the it won't print the section number in the beginning of the section heading.

Answer (score 6):

Use `\section` instead of `\section*`. `\section*` introduces an unnumbered section so the `\label` continues to reference the previous section. If you want to reformat the way the appendix heading is formatted then change the format using [one of the many methods for doing so](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sections).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think Lev's answer is the right way to do things. But in case you have really some attachment to `\section*`, what you can do is to insert `\refstepcounter` manually between the `\section*` command and the `\label` command, as in

```
\section*{Appendix A: xxx}
\refstepcounter{section}
\label{appendix:a}
```